# how to disable curvyCorners?

Tags: jquery, curvycorners

I'm using curvyCorners in an ASP.NET application:

```
<script src='Scripts/curvycorners.src.js' type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var curvyCornersVerbose = false;
    var curvyCornersNoAutoScan = true;

    var settings = {
        tl: { radius: 20 },
        tr: { radius: 20 },
        bl: { radius: 20 },
        br: { radius: 20 },
        antiAlias: true
    }
    curvyCorners(settings, ".page");
</script>
```

my understanding is by doing the above I'm using curvyCorners only for that specific selector and nothing else, but that messes my other page that uses another jquery plugin (multiselect dropdowns).
I tried
1. curvyIgnore class, also didn't work.
2. setting curvyCornersNoAutoScan = ture, it worked partially as not not all control rendered as it should be.

I wonder if I'm doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

i think the curved is applied to anything in your site with .page attribute. so if you got a div in your site that has a .page class then it will be curved. you can try use a different class name in portion of your site you dont want to curve like give it a class name of .page-no-curve

Comment: page class is only applied to the main placeholder on the master page and nothing else. After spending a fair share of time on it, I decided to use malsup round corners instead, I completely ditched this one!! looks like it's till buggy.